# Citrus Framework - Unable to parse JSON data dictionary

Tags: java, citrus-framework

I was trying out the [JSON data dictionaries](http://www.citrusframework.org/reference/html/#json-data-dictionary) section in the Citrus Framework Reference Documentation, and I'm getting this error.

```
10:35:33,430 WARN  ctJsonDataDictionary| Data dictionary unable to parse JSON object
net.minidev.json.parser.ParseException: Unexpected token  at position 0.
    at net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParserBase.readFirst(JSONParserBase.java:369)
    at net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParserBase.parse(JSONParserBase.java:154)
    at net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParserString.parse(JSONParserString.java:58)
    at net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParserString.parse(JSONParserString.java:39)
    at net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:253)
    ...
```

My `citrus-context.xml` has the endpoint and the JSON data dictionary configured.

```
<citrus-http:client id="sampleEndpoint"
                    request-url="localhost:8080/test"
                    request-method="POST"
                    content-type="application/json"
                    timeout="60000" />

<citrus:json-data-dictionary id="samplePayload">
  <citrus:mappings>
    <citrus:mapping path="TestMessage.MessageId" value="messageId"/>
    <citrus:mapping path="TestMessage.CorrelationId" value="correlationId"/>
    <citrus:mapping path="TestMessage.User" value="Christoph"/>
    <citrus:mapping path="TestMessage.TimeStamp" value="citrus:currentDate()"/>
  </citrus:mappings>
</citrus:json-data-dictionary>
```

And my testcase in the XML looks like this.

```
<testcase name="sampleTestCase">
      <meta-info>
          <author>Varun Mulloli</author>
          <creationdate>2015-10-23</creationdate>
          <status>DRAFT</status>
          <last-updated-by>Varun Mulloli</last-updated-by>
          <last-updated-on>2015-10-23T10:35:32</last-updated-on>
      </meta-info>

      <description>TODO: Description</description>

      <actions>
          <send endpoint="sampleEndpoint">
              <message data-dictionary="samplePayload" type="json">
                  <payload/>
              </message>
          </send>
      </actions>
</testcase>
```

I'm able to send the payload and receive a response without using the data dictionary. What am I missing here?

P.S. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA with Maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending an empty message payload and this is why the JSONParser is running into errors. Do not apply the data dictionary on an empty message payload. The data dictionary is only able to overwrite given JSON message elements before send operation takes place.